# How generate login records from timestamp in oracle using sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find out logins for every minute in oracle. I have table as below. login and logout are timestamp(6) datatype

```
login                           | logout
--------------------------------+--------------------------------
14-JAN-21 05.10.38.769000000 AM | 14-JAN-21 05.14.55.046000000 AM
15-JAN-21 10.14.24.304000000 AM | 15-JAN-21 10.17.32.591000000 AM
```

for every record I'm finding minutes of session like bellow

```
login                           | logout                          | minutesBetween
--------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------
14-JAN-21 05.10.38.769000000 AM | 14-JAN-21 05.14.55.046000000 AM | 4
15-JAN-21 10.14.24.304000000 AM | 15-JAN-21 10.17.32.591000000 AM | 3
```

now I'm trying to generate login records by every minute using with clause as below

```
with outer as (
  select
    login,
    logout,
    extract(minute from ((logout - login) )) AS minutesBetween
  from logins_test
),
inner as (
  select
    login + numtodsinterval(rownum,'MINUTE'),
    rownum
  from outer
  connect by level <= minutesBetween
)
select *
from inner;
```

result I', getting is

```
login + numtodsinterval(rownum,'MINUTE') | rownum
-----------------------------------------+--------
14-JAN-21 05.11.38.769000000 AM          | 1
14-JAN-21 05.12.38.769000000 AM          | 2
14-JAN-21 05.13.38.769000000 AM          | 3
14-JAN-21 05.14.38.769000000 AM          | 4
15-JAN-21 10.19.24.304000000 AM          | 5
14-JAN-21 05.16.38.769000000 AM          | 6
15-JAN-21 10.21.24.304000000 AM          | 7
14-JAN-21 05.18.38.769000000 AM          | 8
14-JAN-21 05.19.38.769000000 AM          | 9
15-JAN-21 10.24.24.304000000 AM          | 10
14-JAN-21 05.21.38.769000000 AM          | 11
15-JAN-21 10.26.24.304000000 AM          | 12
14-JAN-21 05.23.38.769000000 AM          | 13
14-JAN-21 05.24.38.769000000 AM          | 14
14-JAN-21 05.25.38.769000000 AM          | 15
15-JAN-21 10.30.24.304000000 AM          | 16
14-JAN-21 05.27.38.769000000 AM          | 17
15-JAN-21 10.32.24.304000000 AM          | 18
14-JAN-21 05.29.38.769000000 AM          | 19
14-JAN-21 05.30.38.769000000 AM          | 20
15-JAN-21 10.35.24.304000000 AM          | 21
14-JAN-21 05.32.38.769000000 AM          | 22
```

I'm expecting 1 record for every minute so overall 7 records

but I'm getting way more records than I expect. Can someone help?

Comment: Please, paste your sample data [as text, not as image](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info).

Comment: @astentx I have made changes

Comment: Also you should provide the results you get from that sample data, because I cannot [reproduce the issue](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dca9b9f9944272a9612697fd919d1a88).

Comment: @astentx I have added what I'm getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be easily achieved by recursive CTE, because `connect by` multiplies the rows from the previous step.

And `ROWNUM` is calculated on entire dataset, so for multiple input rows you'll never have consecutive times.

> ```
> with logins_test as (
>   select
>     1 as id,
>     current_timestamp as login,
>     current_timestamp + NUMTODSINTERVAL(10, 'MINUTE') as logout
>   from dual
>   
>   union all
>   
>   select
>     2 as id,
>     current_timestamp + NUMTODSINTERVAL(2, 'MINUTE') as login,
>     current_timestamp + NUMTODSINTERVAL(6, 'MINUTE') as logout
>   from dual
> )
> , outer as (
>   select
>     id,
>     login,
>     logout,
>     extract(minute from ((logout - login) )) AS minutesBetween
>   from logins_test
> )
> , inner (id, login, newtime, minutesbetween, lvl) as (
>   select
>     id,
>     login,
>     login,
>     minutesbetween,
>     0 as lvl
>   from outer
>   
>   union all
>   
>   /*Increment time by LEVEL minutes*/
>   select
>     id,
>     login,
>     login + NUMTODSINTERVAL(lvl + 1, 'MINUTE'),
>     minutesbetween,
>     lvl + 1
>   from inner
>   where lvl < minutesbetween
> )
> select *
> from inner
> order by id, lvl;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | LOGIN                                  | NEWTIME                                | MINUTESBETWEEN | LVL
> -: | :------------------------------------- | :------------------------------------- | -------------: | --:
>  1 | 14-JAN-21 11.27.32.109571000 AM +00:00 | 14-JAN-21 11.27.32.109571000 AM +00:00 |             10 |   0
>  1 | 14-JAN-21 11.27.32.109571000 AM +00:00 | 14-JAN-21 11.28.32.109571000 AM +00:00 |             10 |   1
>  1 | 14-JAN-21 11.27.32.109571000 AM +00:00 | 14-JAN-21 11.29.32.109571000 AM +00:00 |             10 |   2
>  1 | 14-JAN-21 11.27.32.109571000 AM +00:00 | 14-JAN-21 11.30.32.109571000 AM +00:00 |             10 |   3
>  1 | 14-JAN-21 11.27.32.109571000 AM +00:00 | 14-JAN-21 11.31.32.109571000 AM +00:00 |             10 |   4
>  1 | 14-JAN-21 11.27.32.109571000 AM +00:00 | 14-JAN-21 11.32.32.109571000 AM +00:00 |             10 |   5
>  1 | 14-JAN-21 11.27.32.109571000 AM +00:00 | 14-JAN-21 11.33.32.109571000 AM +00:00 |             10 |   6
>  1 | 14-JAN-21 11.27.32.109571000 AM +00:00 | 14-JAN-21 11.34.32.109571000 AM +00:00 |             10 |   7
>  1 | 14-JAN-21 11.27.32.109571000 AM +00:00 | 14-JAN-21 11.35.32.109571000 AM +00:00 |             10 |   8
>  1 | 14-JAN-21 11.27.32.109571000 AM +00:00 | 14-JAN-21 11.36.32.109571000 AM +00:00 |             10 |   9
>  1 | 14-JAN-21 11.27.32.109571000 AM +00:00 | 14-JAN-21 11.37.32.109571000 AM +00:00 |             10 |  10
>  2 | 14-JAN-21 11.29.32.109571000 AM +00:00 | 14-JAN-21 11.29.32.109571000 AM +00:00 |              4 |   0
>  2 | 14-JAN-21 11.29.32.109571000 AM +00:00 | 14-JAN-21 11.30.32.109571000 AM +00:00 |              4 |   1
>  2 | 14-JAN-21 11.29.32.109571000 AM +00:00 | 14-JAN-21 11.31.32.109571000 AM +00:00 |              4 |   2
>  2 | 14-JAN-21 11.29.32.109571000 AM +00:00 | 14-JAN-21 11.32.32.109571000 AM +00:00 |              4 |   3
>  2 | 14-JAN-21 11.29.32.109571000 AM +00:00 | 14-JAN-21 11.33.32.109571000 AM +00:00 |              4 |   4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=99d736f9cdf9742240f36a1822ca54b2)*